# Prove $E\left[\exp^{ia\int_0^Tf(t) \, dB_t}\right]=\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{2}\int_0^Tf^2(t) \, dt\right)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> How to prove 
>   $$
> \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(ia\int_0^Tf(t) \, dB_t\right)\right]
>  = \exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{2}\int_0^Tf(t)^2 \, dt\right)?
> $$

$B_t$ is the Brownian motion, and $E$ is the expectation. $f(t)$ is the simple step function defined by $f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i1_{(t_{i-1}, t_i]}(t)$ and $\int_0^Tf(t) \, dB_t=\sum_i^nb_i(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}})$.

The question is based on the top lines of page 144 of https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MA5182/brownian-motion-stochastic-calculus.pdf. The definition of $f(t)$ is also from its Eq.(4.6).

Comment: $e^{ia\ldots}$ on the left side is a complex exponent, i.e. $i = \sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: @gt6989b yes, it is

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$Y = \exp\left(ia\int_{0}^tf(s)\,dB_s+\frac{a^2}{2} \int_0^tf(s)^2 \, ds \right) $$

Apply Ito's rule to $Y_t$

$$dY_t =  iaY_tf(t) \, dB_t$$

a drift-less process that leads to $\mathbb{E}[Y_T] = Y_0=1$. Thus,

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(ia\int_{0}^Tf(t) \, dB_t + \frac{a^2}{2} \int_0^Tf(t)^2 \, dt\right)\right]=1$$

or
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(ia\int_0^Tf(t) \, dB_t \right) \right] = \exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{2} \int_0^Tf(t)^2 \, dt \right)
$$